# What happens to WKWebView when scrolled out of bounds

Tags: ios, swift, wkwebview

I'm using a paged scroll view displaying different web views as pages. The scroll view has set `clipsToBounds = false` to allow the display of previous and following pages in the scroll view.

When scrolling through the pages, there is one exact moment, where the WKWebViews content becomes completely invisible. This happens exactly at the moment, where the web view leaves the bounds of the scroll view (see below). On some websites, the visible content out of the bounds is different to the actual content.

[image: wkwebview hides]
[image: wkwebview different content]

These problems only occur when using WKWebView instead of UIWebView (Everything works as intended with UIWebView).

Has someone experienced similar issues with the WKWebView and has a solution for them?

*EDIT:*
There is a now a **sample project** on Github, where you can experience the bug and play around with it:
[WKWebView test project](https://github.com/j0h4nn3s/WKWebViewBUG/tree/master)

Comment: It is an interesting bug. I'm sure there is a better solution but I guess you can fix it by using UICollectionview for scrolling and loads first three page. After you scroll, you can load other pages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To figure it out i think you need to use UICollectionView. 
The cell should exist with WKWebView while it will be on screen.

1) You need to place it like [Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gdUsS.png)

And next problem will be to make content pageble. 
2) To do it right you need to add UIScrollView over your collection like [Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/10NYz.png)

3) After, make your UIScrollView pageble and write in viewdidload:
`collectionView.addGestureRecognizer(scrollView.panGestureRecognizer)`

4) After you receive models for showing in UICOllectionView - update your contentSize of UIScrollView like

```
scrollView.contentSize = CGSize(width: (models.count*(cellWidth+cellIndent) + sectionIndent * 2), height: cellHeight)
```

5) Implement UIScrollViewDelegate

```
extension YourVC: UIScrollViewDelegate {
    func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
        if scrollView == self.scrollView {
            collectionView.contentOffset = scrollView.contentOffset
        } else if scrollView == self.collectionView {
            self.scrollView.contentOffset = scrollView.contentOffset
        }
    }
}
```

Thats it. Happy coding =)

Comment: I was hoping for a not so complex solution but this works. I used a normal UIView instead of a UICollectionView.

Answer (score 0):

WKWebView is designed to be more performant than UIWebView.  It will stop running some parts of a webpage or stop rendering it completely if it is not on top of the view hierarchy.  The problem here is that once the webpage is out of the bounds of the scrollview, WKWebView does not consider itself to be on screen even though it is visible by virtue of setting `clipsToBounds = false`.

The easiest thing to do would be to use UIWebView.  If for some reason you need WebKit, consider adjusting you paging code so your scrollview spans the entire view controller.

Comment: I can't use UIWebView for multiple reasons. Also I don't want to use components which are considered to be deprecated.